# customize woocommerce error edit-adress and edit-account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to customize woocommerce error edit-adress and edit account !

/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php

```
foreach ( $required_fields as $field_key => $field_name ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST[ $field_key ] ) ) {
        /* translators: %s: Field name. */
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $field_name ) . '</strong>' ), 'error', array( 'id' => $field_key ) );
    }
```

hook for customize wc_add_notice edit account??

```
    // Validation: Required fields.
    if ( ! empty( $field['required'] ) && empty( $value ) ) {
        /* translators: %s: Field name. */
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), $field['label'] ), 'error', array( 'id' => $key ) );
    }
```

hook for customize wc_add_notice edit-adress??

Please please help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_' . $notice_type, $message );` filter hook. This will allows you to override or append your custom message.

And, for only applying to the edit-address page you can use the `is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' )` function to check whether you are on that page or not.

```
function custom_wc_add_notice( $message ){
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ){
        $message .= ' Your custom message';
    }
    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
```

**You can also override `notices` templates.**

**Copy templates from here**

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/notices

**and upload here**

> wp-content/themes/your-active-theme-name/notices

**For notice.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Show messages
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/notices/notice.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.9.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

if ( ! $notices ) {
    return;
}

if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ){

    // modify the below code as per your need.

    foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-info"<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; 

}else{

    foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-info"<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;   

}

?>
```

**For error.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Show error messages
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/notices/error.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.9.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! $notices ) {
    return;
}

if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ){ ?>

    <!-- modify the below code as per your need. -->

    <ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
        <?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
            <li<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
                <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<?php }else{ ?>

    <ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
        <?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
            <li<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
                <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

**For success.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Show messages
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/notices/success.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.9.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! $notices ) {
    return;
}

if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ){ 

    // modify the below code as per your need.

    foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-message"<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?> role="alert">
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; 

}else{

    foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-message"<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?> role="alert">
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; 

}

?>
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: The hook is for checkout  :  function filter_woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice( $sprintf, $field_label ) {
 $sprintf = sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), '' . esc_html( $field_label ) . '' );
    return $sprintf; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice', 10, 2 ); ////  is not for edit-address and edit account???

Comment: Yes `woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice` is for checkout not for `edit-address and edit account`

Comment: Can't select message for each field? example : function custom_wc_add_notice( $message ){
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ){
 if ( empty($_POST['account_first_name']) ) {
        $message = 'text 1';
 } 
 if ( empty($_POST['account_last_name']) ) {
        $message = 'text 2';
 }  
    }
    return $message;
}